# Does the Hotspot JVM cache result of deterministic functions (methods)?

Tags: optimization, jvm-hotspot, deterministic

... and if yes, what are the general do's and don'ts?

E.g.

- Can I instantiate other classes, can they use virtual methods as usual?
- Will it be detected whether any part of the arguments or the instantiated object graph contains reference to some global state?
- Will it be detected if the objects, passed as arguments, are immutable?